# Write to next empty row in matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, nested-loops

I have a rather complicated set of 5 nested for loops that generate a pair of values on each iteration (say x and y) and I'd like to put each pair of values onto a new row in a matrix.

Usually, I would just write something like:

```
X = zeros(n, 2)

for i = 1:n

X(i, :) = newrow

end
```

But I'm not sure how this would work with the set of 5 loops. Is it possible to write each new pair of values to the next empty row in a matrix? Currently I'm just starting with a 1x2 matrix and appending a new row on every iteration, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use this within the innermost loop, without preallocating `X`. **Not recommended** (see approach 2).

   ```
   X(end+1, :) = newrow;
   ```
2. A **better approach** (to avoid memory reallocation) would be to preallocate your matrix to the final size and then index each row using a row counter that you increase witin the innermost loop:

   ```
   X = NaN(1000,2); %// for example. "1000" <-- product of number of iterations
   r = 0;
   for ii = 1:10
      for jj = 1:100
          r = r + 1; %// increase row counter
          X(r,:) = newrow;
      end
   end
   ```

Comment: +1 for the second approach. Growing a matrix within 5 loops doesn't sound like a good idea. In fact I would switch the order in your answer so the "preferred" approach comes first.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. I've edited the answer to make that clearer

Comment: Thanks, the second approach is great. I thought of using a counter but didn't realise it would be so simple.

Growing the matrix within 5 loops is what I was already doing and looking to avoid. I was thinking finding the first row of all 0s each time and writing to that might work, but counting is better.